# MySQL Case function to insert into table not working right

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to assign genders to authors names in a new table with three current tables: author names, maleNames and femaleNames. But in the new table, all the names have the same gender.

```
Insert Into Genders 
Select first_name
   , case when first_name in (select first_name from malesName) then “male” 
     when first_name in (select first_name from femalesName) then “female”
     when first_name in (select first_name from malesName) 
          and first_name in (select first_name from femalesName) 
     then “both” 
     end 
from philosophy_authors
;
```

That is my query, how can I fix this?

Comment: Mysql syntax is IF.  Look that up.

Comment: @Bleach `CASE WHEN x THEN y END` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm not sure mysql queries will work with the `“` and `”` double quotes, better use a single quote: `'`.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information,like original data and actual results _"all the names have the same gender"_ is about as vague as you could be short of omitting your query altogether. Also, double quotes should be fine, but those look like weird double quotes to me, should look like `"`; not like the directional ones from unicode.

Comment: Also, you'll never get your "both" outcome unless it is the first WHEN test; any name that would pass it's conditions would've passed the earlier ones.

Comment: @Uueerdo an example of what I am talking about is that I have an author with the name of Mary, a name that is recognized as a female name. But when I run this query, in the new table created the associated gender with Mary is male. I also tried putting both first, but then every name in the list has an associated gender of both which should also not be the case.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of the content of your `malesName` and `femalesName` tables?